# Error : Unable to load Main Class from JAR file on running spark-submit command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, spark-submit

I created the Jar for my Scala project and then ran the following command from the terminal ["com.sukrit.hbase_" is the package name and "Filters_Usage" is the scala class that I want to run]

```
Macintosh:bin sukritmehta$ ./spark-submit --class "com.sukrit.hbase_.Filters_Usage" --master local[*] "/Users/sukritmehta/Desktop/Sukrit/Spark_Hbase/target/Spark_Hbase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

But after running this, I am encountering the following errors :

```
20/04/24 20:53:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error: Failed to load class com.sukrit.hbase_.Filters_Usage.
20/04/24 20:53:02 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/04/24 20:53:02 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/d4/psn4wv8s7tjbfgt6gkt35z9c0000gq/T/spark-ae120675-a1c6-4300-997c-bd53f9f35187
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spark_Hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spark_Hbase</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- Scala and Spark dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId> <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.7</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId> <version>2.1.1</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId> <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

          <!--  <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>      --> 



        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
              <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version> <!-- Hortonworks Latest -->
        </dependency>


         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Filters_Usage.scala

```
package com.sukrit.hbase_
import org.apache.hadoop.conf
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter._


object Filters_Usage {


    def printRow(result : Result) = {
      val cells = result.rawCells();
      print( Bytes.toString(result.getRow) + " : " )
      for(cell <- cells){
        val col_name = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell))
        val col_value = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell))
        print("(%s:%s) ".format(col_name, col_value))
      }
      println()
    }


  def main(args : Array[String]) {


    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark_Hbase_Connection").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()    

    conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout", "1800000");
    conf.set("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period", "1800000");
    // establish a connection
    val connection:Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)

    // Table on which different commands have to be run.
    val tableName = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("emp"))

    sc.addJar("/Users/sukritmehta/Desktop/Sukrit/Spark_Hbase/target/Spark_Hbase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")

    println("\n **************** All rows in Table **************** \n ")
    val scan:Scan = new Scan()  
    val resultScanner:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(scan)
    resultScanner.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner.close()
    println(" \n \n ")









    // **************** Row Filters ****************

    println("**************** Row Filter (for Row_keys <=5) **************** \n ")
    val row_filter1 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("5")));
    scan.setFilter(row_filter1)
    val resultScanner1:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(scan)
    resultScanner1.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner1.close()
    println(" \n \n ")



    println("**************** Row Filter (for Row_keys starting with 1) **************** \n ")
    val row_filter2 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                  new SubstringComparator("1"));
    scan.setFilter(row_filter2)
    val resultScanner2:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(scan)
    resultScanner2.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner2.close()
    println(" \n \n ")









    // **************** Family Filters ****************

    println("**************** Family Filter (for Col Family = personal data) **************** \n ")
    val fam_filter1 = new FamilyFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("personal data")));
    scan.setFilter(fam_filter1)
    val resultScanner3:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(scan)
    resultScanner3.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner3.close()
    println(" \n \n ")









    // **************** Qualifier Filters ****************

    println("**************** Qualifier Filter (for Column = name) **************** \n ")
    val qual_filter1 = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("name")));
    scan.setFilter(qual_filter1)
    val resultScanner4:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(scan)
    resultScanner4.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner4.close()
    println(" \n \n ")



    println("**************** Qualifier Filter (Printing name corresponding to Row_Key = 5) **************** \n ")
    val qual_filter2 = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("name")));
    scan.setFilter(qual_filter2)
    val get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("5")); get.setFilter(qual_filter2);
    val result = tableName.get(get); 
    printRow(result)
    println(" \n \n ")









     // **************** Filter List ****************

    println("**************** Filter List (print all rows between two row_Keys 4 & 7 (lexicograpphically)) **************** \n ")
    val ss = new Scan()
    val filter1 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("4")));

    val filter2 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, 
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("7")));

    var filterList = new FilterList()
    filterList.addFilter(filter1)
    filterList.addFilter(filter2)

    ss.setFilter(filterList)    
    val resultScanner8:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss)
    resultScanner8.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner8.close()
    println(" \n \n ")









    // **************** Single Column Value Filter ****************

    println("**************** Single Column Value Filter (print all rows having cities lesser than Delhi (lexicographically)) **************** \n ")
    val ss3 = new Scan()

    val filter5 = new SingleColumnValueFilter( Bytes.toBytes("personal data"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("city"),
                  CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Delhi")));
    filter5.setFilterIfMissing(false);


    ss3.setFilter(filter5)    
    val resultScanner10:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss3)
    resultScanner10.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner10.close()
    println(" \n \n ")










    // **************** Filter List ****************

    println("**************** Filter List (print all rows between Delhi and Mumbai (lexicographically)) **************** \n ")


    println("****** Before filtering ****** \n ")
    val ss2 = new Scan()
    val resultScanner9:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss2)
    resultScanner9.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner9.close()
    println(" \n \n ")



    println("****** After filtering ****** \n ")
    val filter3 = new SingleColumnValueFilter( Bytes.toBytes("personal data"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("city"),
                  CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Delhi")));
    filter3.setFilterIfMissing(false);

    val filter4 = new SingleColumnValueFilter( Bytes.toBytes("personal data"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("city"),
                  CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Mumbai")));
    filter4.setFilterIfMissing(false);

    var filterList2 = new FilterList()
    filterList2.addFilter(filter3)
    filterList2.addFilter(filter4)

    ss2.setFilter(filterList2)    
    val resultScanner6:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss2)
    resultScanner6.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner6.close()
    println(" \n \n ")










    // **************** Filter List ****************

    println("**************** Filter List (print all rows Having DOBs between 19770101 and 19951231 (lexicographically)) **************** \n ")

    println("****** Before filtering ****** \n ")
    val ss4 = new Scan()
    val resultScanner11:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss4)
    resultScanner11.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner11.close()
    println(" \n \n ")



    println("****** After filtering ****** \n ")
    val filter7 = new SingleColumnValueFilter( Bytes.toBytes("personal data"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("dob"),
                  CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("19770101")));

    val filter8 = new SingleColumnValueFilter( Bytes.toBytes("personal data"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("dob"),
                  CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
                  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("19951231")));

    var filterList3 = new FilterList()
    filterList3.addFilter(filter7)
    filterList3.addFilter(filter8)

    ss4.setFilter(filterList3)    
    val resultScanner12:ResultScanner = tableName.getScanner(ss4)
    resultScanner12.asScala.foreach(result => {
        printRow(result)
    })
    resultScanner12.close()
    println(" \n \n ")







  }

}
```

It would be great if anyone could help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: There is special symbol in your jar path .. is your jar files available in same path ?

Comment: That character got added by mistake. Updated it now.

Comment: Can you post your main class code ?

Comment: Just Posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting your scala code is not compiled properly, can you add below to you pom.xml & change the paths as per your local system.

```
 <build>
        <directory>../target/scala-2.11</directory>
        <outputDirectory>../target/scala-2.11</outputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>../src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>../src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>client.MxClient</Main-Class>
                                        <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                                        <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>
                                        META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister
                                    </resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: how you compiled & created jar file ?

Comment: The build was successful on running this command :Macintosh:Spark_Hbase sukritmehta$ ${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn clean package

Comment: if you use that plugin, you have to run maven command like - mvn clean scala:compile -DdisplayCmd=true -DrecompileMode=all package. try this

Comment: Hey Srinivas, I added this block of "build" and updated the directories and ran the maven using the above command that you mentioned. But, still that same error of Unable to load the file is coming up.

Comment: Moreover, I am able run this code easily through eclipse. But, I am finding difficulty through this spark-submit command method.

Comment: one last - can you try executing jar files using - scala cp <class name> & check is it executing your main method or not.

Comment: Not able run this through terminal.